# mongoose create function in not function error(sub document)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

**schema**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...,
  suported: [{name:String, id:String}],
  suporting: [{name:String, id:String}]

},
  { timestamps: true });
```

**Query**

```
const requester = await User.findOne({ _id }) 
const suporter = await User.findOne({ _id: _idSuporter })
        // Result ok
         requester.suported.create(data); // causing error
          suporter.suporting.create(data);
```

**Error message:** requester.suported.create is not a function.

**Edited**
Links to where you can see what I am expecting

1. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#adding-subdocs-to-arrays
2. https://attacomsian.com/blog/mongoose-subdocuments

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because it is not possible to call the create function on the "supported" attribute of the User object. What you can do is create a static function that takes the data as a parameter and does something when the function is called, like this:

```
userSchema.statics.createSupported = function(data: any) {
     // do something here..
}

userSchema.statics.createSupporting = function(data: any) {
     // do something here..
}
```

And when you call the query:

```
const requester = await User.findOne({ _id })
const supporter = await User.findOne({ _id: _idSuporter })
// Result ok
User.createSupported(date)
User.createSupporting(data)
```

Comment: SoftCare: https://attacomsian.com/blog/mongoose-subdocuments      at the extreme end is the same as what I want to archive.  
  And I am trying to avoid Multiple queries... not to overwhelm the database

Comment: If you want to save a subdocument nested in a document, you can simply save the subdocument id in the document and then when you want to query nested fields, just call the populate function. Thus, the data were not saved in the document, but a reference, not being exhaustive for the query. Is this what you expect? If yes, I can edit my answer..

Comment: pls, put the answer below... I don't really understand...

Comment: You can see the nested document be query like the main schema. To use find, create, delete. Just open the above link and see the doc